# Web API 2 default routing scheme

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

This question suddenly pops up in my mind.

In `Startup.cs` I have:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

When I have a method like this one:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Order")]
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    // don't use any attribute here
    public IHttpActionResult HelloWorld()
    {
        ...
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

---

1. Is it possible to access `HelloWorld()`?
2. Should a `GET` or `POST` or whatever action be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to `HttpWorld()` using GET if you rename your method as: `GetHelloWorld()`.
The same with POST renaming to `PostHelloWorld()`.

But I prefer using `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, ... attributes, even if my action methods has the "Get" or "Post" characters in the name, to avoid possible errors.

**Updated**

After making some tests, I realised that my comments about that is not possible to call the HelloWorld are not correct.
Indeed it is possible to call your HelloWorld() method if you make a POST call to `http://<YourProjectUrl>/order`.

So, the default method will be POST and, as you haven't configured any Route for your action method (take in account that RoutePrefix is just a prefix, so needs a Route attribute to be considered), it will get your controller name without "Controller" (OrderController -> Order).

Comment: Absolutely agreed. I just wonder what happens without renaming method names and adding attributes as shown in the aforementioned scenario.

Comment: @AldourCheng I don't know if I understand you. If you add attributes it will work as expected: [HttpGet] will allow GET, and [HttpPost] will allow POST, independently of your method names.

Comment: Ya I understand that, but what I am asking is, without modifying anything in the code snippet provided in my question, what route and actions does `HelloWorld()` accept?

Comment: @AldourCheng Ah ok! I got it. I'm quite sure it's not going to accept any get or post. Think that, allowing handling methods that have 'Get', 'Put' or 'Post' in their names is an extra feature added on the ASP.NET Web Api framework to allow not using [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes. So, handling something like 'HelloWorld()' must me implemented expressly. Maybe, it's possible to extend some action handler class to achieve it. Not very useful, however (in my opinion).

Comment: @AldourCheng I have updated my answer, because indeed there is way to to call your HelloWorld() method making a POST to http://yoursite/order. Sorry for my mistake.